# How are multiple clients handled in (Java-based) TCP?

Tags: java, networking, tcp, client-server, nio

I feel these might be basic topics, but I couldn't find them succinctly answered elsewhere.

When building a TCP server, my understanding is that each connecting client has to be farmed off to its own port in order to maintain sensible connectivity (e.g. to know that *this* message is coming from *this* client).

How does one set this up? I assume that you'd have a List and a dedicated 'entry point' Socket that people connected to. The connecting Socket would find a free port, reply with the port number, and set up a new Socket listening on that port. Does this sound about right?

If this is the case, it seems to me that the entry Socket would need to block while listening for incoming connections. Is this blocking read done on a separate thread?

Additional side-question: I really just need some simple message-passing for a basic Java game I want to experiment with. Things like Netty seem like a sledgehammer for this particular walnut of an application. Am I best off writing something nice and lightweight using the Java standard library?

Comment: In the old time of jdk1.02 I wrote a web server that simply gave the newly created socket (obtained from ServerSocket.accept()) to a thread (in a pool).

Comment: "Each connecting client has to be farmed off to its own port". This is your mistake. The accepted socket uses the same local port as the listening socket. What is different is the socket itself. There is nothing to set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main socket is called a "mother socket" and you block on it waiting for new connections.  When a new connection happens, you use the `accept()` method which creates a new socket just for the new client.

You can manage these sockets by using a `Selector`.  You configure the selector to listen to the mother socket and also any other sockets that you created.  This way, you can have one thread listening for all incoming communication.  If the new communication is on the mother socket, you accept the connection and generate a new socket and add it to the selector.  If the new communication is on one of the other sockets, then you handle the message appropriately.

I always write my own networking code.  It's a useful learning experience, but you also know exactly what these things are doing.

Comment: Could you take a peek at @artbristol's reply and see if you differ on your advice? art says "the client continues to use the same destination port" but that seems to be at odds with what you say here.

 Really lovely reply, by the way! Very complete. Thanks.

Comment: I modified the answer appropriately.  @artbristol is right about the ports, but this detail is abstracted away by Java.

Comment: Thanks a lot, to both of you. I selected this one as the answer in the end simply because it had more practical mentions and answered the Netty subquestion, you were both very helpful however!

Comment: @mtrc You don't 'generate a new socket'. The `accept()` method *returns* a new socket to you.

Answer (score 1):

The client continues to use the same TCP destination port. Multiple connections are handled by the TCP stack based on the IP address and *source* port (randomly chosen by the client). You don't really need to concern yourself with this though. See the Oracle Java IO tutorials for how to deal with handing off connections to separate threads, they are rather good.

Comment: Could you take a look at @Erick's reply and see if you differ on your advice? Erick says that you create 'a new socket on a different port' as I guessed in my question, but you mention that this isn't necessary. Just wondered where you both were coming from.

Comment: You create a new Socket *object*, but it represents the particular TCP connection rather than the concept of a listening server (which is what ServerSocket represents). Fire up a browser and Wireshark, and take a look. You'll see all the connections are still using port 80.

Comment: That's fantastic, I learnt a lot in about five minutes! Thanks.

Comment: @mtrc You don't 'create a new socket object'. The `accept()` method returns it to you.